# Why can't I use the_permalink() with echo in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code:

```
<?php
    query_posts(array(
        'posts_per_page'   => -1,
        'post_type' => 'sample-letter',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    ));

    while(have_posts()){
        the_post();

        echo '<div class="col-md-9"><span class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">title</a></span><br />';
    }

    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

It works great but the problem is, I can't use:

```
<?php the_permalink() ?>
```

INSIDE the `echo` statement. It is a simple link, and rather than render the link url, it outputs:

```
http://sitename.com/<?php the_permalink() ?>
```

Instead of:

```
http://sitename.com/thelink
```

How can I make this loop work without the `echo`? Is that actually the problem at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `echo` part like;

```
echo '<div class="col-md-9"><span class="title"><a href="' . the_permalink() . '" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to ' . the_title_attribute() . '">title</a></span><br />';
```

or you can use;

```
$current_post_id = get_the_ID(); // id of current post in the loop
$permalink = get_permalink( $current_post_id );
$title = get_the_title( $current_post_id );

echo '<div class="col-md-9"><span class="title"><a href="' . $permalink . '" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to ' . $title . '">' . $title . '</a></span><br />';
```

Comment: That works great! One problem though, this now links to the same page i am on. Any idea how to get it to link to the single post page for each instance in the query?

Comment: @lowercase You can use `the_ID` as parameter in `get_permalink`. See my updated answer

Comment: that works better, but before doing what it should, it lists every ID and title in a big string. why is that/how do i get rid of it?

Comment: @lowercase It was my mistake. I used `the_ID` instead of `get_the_ID`. I fixed it, See my updated answer

Comment: better again! but one last problem. how do i get the post title to show as the link? I am using ' . the_title .' in place of the word 'title' above, but it breaks the link.

Comment: You can do that with `get_the_title($current_post_id)`. See my updated answer

Comment: PERFECT! Much appreciated for you help.